# Time Complexity of Max-Heap Solution to k-th Smallest Problem

Tags: queue, time-complexity, priority-queue, heap

I was looking at the Max-Heap LC solution to the k-th smallest points problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/discuss/1647773/. I understand how, using a PriorityQueue, the time complexity would be O(Nlogk) -- since each insertion is O(logk).

However, I noticed that building a heap in the Min-Heap solution was O(N) time. Suppose we used a non-PriorityQueue solution with buildHeap to build a max heap up until it contains *k* elements. After *k* elements, the push-popping needs to occur, which is O(logk) each. Using this solution, would the time complexity be O(k + (N-k)logk))? Is O(Nlogk) time better than this time complexity for all k<N? Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the link I think they are using the exact same logic as yours but the reason they have stated O(Nlogk) instead of O(k + (N-k)logk)) is probably because it is assumed k is small compared to N. In that case they are equivalent. But your complexity seems the correct one in general.

Comment: Your time complexity is better in general the code linked can be turned into your time complexity with slight modification. If len(heap) < k they should not use heappush but rather append it to a list and when it hits length k for the first time they should heapify and heappushpop after that, that changes Nlogk to k+(N-k)logk

Comment: Remember that big-O notation ignores multiplicative constants and lower order terms so, for example, T(n) = c0 + c1*n + c2*n^2 is O(n^2).